# Asynchronously configuring UITableViewCells on iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've noticed that in several iOS apps, notably Facebook's app, the developers have improved scrolling performance in their table views by first displaying an empty cell and then asynchronously configuring the cell. This means that `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` executes quickly allowing the view to scroll smoothly.

I'm wondering what the best way to mimic this effect would be, does anyone have an idea of how it's done?

Comment: Refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Asynchronously loading an image isn't my problem. In this case I'm using core data and the data faulting mechanism slows down table cell configuration, being able to do that asynchronously would speed things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your data getting is slow , you can also use like LazyLoad mechanism . You can set all your data is the default text like @"loading" , and asynchronously loading your data . When it calls back , you can change the data from the default text. Or you can set your default data is nil first (like "Evernote")

Comment: That's probably a better approach than waiting to populate the cell. Thanks!